# Google API Bug - Attribution Inconsistency

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, google-places-api

Fetching photo data for a place using `Google Places API` HTTP web service call URL,

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=<LOCATION>&radius=<RADIUS>&sensor=false&key=<API_KEY>`

yields the expected callback. Here is the response from a request I am using for testing.

```
2017-09-19 11:20:32.968347-0400 <MY_APP_NAME>[7502:2809094] Places Found: (
        {
        ... 
        ...
        photos =         (
                        {
                height = 5312;
                "html_attributions" =                 (
                    "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110407035205544174409/photos\">leah steen</a>"
                );
                "photo_reference" = "CmRaAAAAcppPDrYGBnLqlyYQ_EMmsvgKXXpVjp0drGkJPWLBwlSzrWzuhtFFGCzQPl1pSez92QVktthtaMSsV1IlAWMIMPboycElhruKgUg-KFHWWrhLKOR6h8GGiR349rhokAFJEhApc7ghYIH0guUQBGJi1bKBGhQMcElN7-lSBzvCgAG3vVzANLkf6A";
                width = 2988;
            }
        );
        ...
        ...
    }
)
```

As you can see, this place has a photo dictionary containing an `html_attributions` value for the associated image, which I am handling appropriately throughout my application.

#### ISSUE:

When I fetch the photo data for the same place, by using the place_id, I get this for the photo and attribution:

```
2017-09-19 11:22:08.548253-0400 <MY_APP_NAME>[7502:2809094] photo data: (
    "<UIImage: 0x17048b720> size {169, 300} orientation 0 scale 2.000000",
    "leah steen{\n}"
)
```

I receive of course the same photo, **but an attribution WITHOUT a link**. As you can see from my other method using the web service, the photo for this place **does indeed** have an attribution **with** a link.

I am at a loss. How am I supposed to get the full attribution from Google if their iOS SDK does not return the same data?

#### CODE:

Using Google's *other* suggested method for fetching photo data for a place via the `place_id` you can obtain the image and the images attribution (if it has one).

I fetch the data using these two methods as Google asks:

```
- (void)lookUpPhotosForPlaceID:(NSString *)placeID
                      callback:(GMSPlacePhotoMetadataResultCallback)callback;

- (void)loadPlacePhoto:(GMSPlacePhotoMetadata *)photo
              callback:(GMSPlacePhotoImageResultCallback)callback;
```

Here is the code I use for fetching the photo data.

```
// Look up photos for the place
[[GMSPlacesClient sharedClient] lookUpPhotosForPlaceID:placeID callback:^(GMSPlacePhotoMetadataList * _Nullable photos, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    
    if (error != nil) {
        response(error, NULL);
        return;
    }
    
    if (photos.results.count > 0) {
        
        GMSPlacePhotoMetadata *metaData = photos.results.firstObject;   // Using the first photo
        
        // Load the photo
        [[GMSPlacesClient sharedClient] loadPlacePhoto:metaData constrainedToSize:<SOME_SIZE> scale:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.screen.scale callback:^(UIImage * _Nullable photo, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            
            if (error) {
                response(error, NULL);
                return;
            }
            
            NSArray *photoData = @[photo, metaData.attributions];
            
            response(nil, photoData);
            
        }];
        
    }
    else response(error, NULL);
    
}];
```

**EDIT:**

For reference, as Google *does* inform it's users that this data may be subject to change, and that multiple callbacks *should* return the same data. Yet multiple calls using different API's do not...

Answer (score 2):

You can do couple of thing to verify correct behaviour:

1. You can switch back to first API and see whether it actually returns it again. Because doc says:

> Multiple calls of this method will probably return the same photos
>   each time. However, this is not guaranteed because the underlying data
>   may have changed.

2. Second you can check the callback behaviour if you are losing some data when callback is called in line

   NSArray *photoData = @[photo, metaData.attributions];

At this point it me be loosing attributed string but only retains plain text(leah steen). 
Good way to check this metaData is before *loadPlacePhoto:callback:*

Comment: Thanks for the answer - while calling the first API may deliver the attributed string, there is no reason the alternate API (iOS) call should be delivering different information. Multiple calls will indeed return the same information, but having monitored the attribution by leah, it has not changed. Over 20+ tests of similar cases show the same results - the iOS never returns the attributed string, only the Web call. I'm not going to use one quota when there is another (iOS) available that queries the same data